# Downloading applications in windows 10 for access across users

Tags: windows-10

How can I download an application (Firefox, Chrome, Eclipse, PyCharm etc.) so that all users on the device can access it fully?

I have previously tried to install the Eclipse and PyCharm inside the Program Files and Program Files (x86) folders, but I could only access it in the user that downloaded it.

All users other than main user are local accounts, and not connected to Microsoft. The local accounts also have administrator permissions.

Comment: Almost all installations include an option for installing to all users, to be set during the installation. The installation folder isn't the way to do that.

Comment: I have never encountered that. Example: Firefox download for windows 64-bit. It immediately downloaded the exe folder, and upon clicking the exe folder, it immediately installed Firefox and opened the browser. @harrymc

Comment: Many applications now use the (more mac like) model of installing to your local AppData folder.  If this is what the installation dev was told to install to, there is very little you can do about it other than reverse engineer the app reqs yourself.

Comment: If the install is run as an administrator it should install per system or should ask per system or per user. If install is run as an ordinary user it should install per user. See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/installation-context. Your installer may also support *Administrative Install* where it copies setup to a folder for other uses to install from hard drive.

Comment: Managed to install Eclipse into the Program Files folder using the Run as Admin on the installer. However, it still created the .eclipse and .p2 folders in the ~\Users\[userName] folder, though this seems like an eclipse issue rather than install method issue. So thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For installations that don't have an option for installing to all users,
it may be possible to install to all users from any administrator account
by right-click on the installer and selecting "Run as Administrator".

That is the case for Firefox - see
[link](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/919880).